# Access ag-Grid ColumnApi in static method in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I need to use ColumnApi which i imported from `ag-grid-community` to a static method. So I assigned this as a static variable and try to use this.

```
import { ColumnApi } from 'ag-grid-community';

export class GridConfig {
  constructor() {}

  public static columnApi: ColumnApi;

  public static readonly nextCell = () {
     console.log('columnApi ', GridConfig.columnApi); //undefined
  }
}
```

Here whenever I use GridConfig.columnApi it return undefined. So how can I use columnApi inside my static method ?

Comment: where is the rest of the code where you initialize the grid?